# Laravel Установка на хостинг с SSL

Tags: laravel

Пытаюсь поставить laravel на обычный хостинг apache.
В .htaccess Сделал редирект на public
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]

Как сделать при этом редирект на https ?

Answer (score 1):

У вас не правильно настроен хост. Редирект на public делать небезопасно. В конфигурации хоста apache Вам нужно указать путь до public, а не до коренной папки с проектом.
И затем в .htaccess написать примерно следующее:

```
#Редирект на HTTPS 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```